# How to specify a multipart form field is optional in OpenAPI/Swagger v3?

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator, oas3

I'd like to outline a multipart form request body, with some fields which are required, and other fields which are optional. Generally, in OAS Schema Objects, all properties not explicitly marked with `required: true` are defaulted to optional. However, when outlining a `requestBody` with `multipart/form-data` content, this seems to go by the wayside, and all fields are required.

I have tried multiple ways of designating the fields required vs optional. I receive compilation errors when trying to explicitly designate a field as optional with `required: false`.

OAS3 spec:

```yaml
requestBody:
  required: true
  content:
    multipart/form-data:
      schema:
        type: object
        required:
          - foo
        properties:
          foo:
            type: string
            format: binary
          bar:
            type: string
            format: binary
```

Expected: Detail a `multipart/form-data` `requestBody` with some fields required and some optional.

In the code example above, `foo` should be a required file, while `bar` should be an optional file.

Comment: Your schema is correct. If some tool handles `bar` as a required field, it's a bug in that tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an array of required fields, for example, if you'd like do make just foo required, should be like that:

```
requestBody:
  content:
    multipart/form-data:
      schema:
        type: object
        required: [foo]
        properties:
          foo:
            type: string
            format: binary
          bar:
            type: string
            format: binary
```

If you'd like to add more than one, just add the name on the array, such as [foo,bar].